# Loss of pivot columns when using pivotcaches.create with new data source

Tags: excel, vba, caching, pivot-table

I am faced with an issue with my data and pivot table VBA.
My data now adds a new blank column on the far left. I must delete this column so that my data fits in the correct range and the column all have a header as before. When I delete this column, the range of the source data changes minus the deleted column.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent the data source from changing when
   deleting the column?
2. Is there a way to prevent the following vba
   from removing the missing columns in the pivot table that are not
   found in the new data.

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Data2", Version:=6)`

This line of code seems to remove columns from the pivot for the pivot table field instead of leaving them. I have already ensured the following options are set before running the code above:

- Preserve cell formatting on update - is checked
- Number of items to retain per field - is set to max

When the code runs, it reverts the "Number of items to retain per field" back to automatic and I lose the columns.

Comment: Instead of `.ChangePivotCache` suggest to redefine the `SourceData` (i.e.: your code changes the `SourceData` to the name `Data2`, assuming the `SourceData` before the change is a named `Data1` just try redefining the name `Data1` to the required size.

Comment: It is not named but I could make that happen and try it out. Thanks

Comment: So the existing source data is not named and of the format 'Test Data Insert'!$A$2:$P$100000. So redefining the name will not work without losing my columns.

Comment: So you have a sheet named "Administration Review" where a pivottable named "PivotTable2" refers to range A2:P100000 of a sheet named "Test Data Insert". I erroneously thought, that the `PivotTable(...).PivotCache.Sourcedata` could be set easily to another Range (while preventing a table update), but did not succeed either. So I deleted my answer. Sorry.

Comment: Are the headers of the prior `SourceData` and new `SourceData` the same?

Comment: It seems that Excel is performing as designed, however in order to explain the discrepancies between your expectations and the performance of excel, we need relevant information such as (include all these in your post) :  
1. Screenshot of the `PivotTable` before applying the `ChangePivotCache` command,  
2. Screenshot of the original `SourceData` range, ensure that the header is included (highlight the column you need to delete), and   
3. Screenshot of the `Data2` range (including header)

Comment: They are not the same until I run some VBA to make them the same.

Comment: So this two SourceDatas are different and located in different addresses, then you ran some vba procedures to make then the same (i.e. to contain the same fields\header) its that correct?.  
BTW the [PivotTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable) properties associated with `Preserve cell formatting on update` and `Number of items to retain per field` have nothing to do with a [PivotField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield)`.Orientation`